# Autocomplete not listing result properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am getting response through autofill which i can view through inspect in chrome. But I couldn't display properly neither i am getting any result in console.log

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(function() {

  $("#search_text").autocomplete({
      source: "/find_city",
      minLength: 1,
      data:$('#search_text').val(),
      success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
      }

  });

});
})
```

[image]

Comment: I see two bullets under your **Departure Airport** `input` tag.

Comment: Yes, bu i couldn't style them. As when i go click there to inspect autocomplete result quickly vanishes

Comment: You can use `ul.ui-menu li.ui-menu-item` to style individual `li` of the autocomplete results.

Answer (score 0):

Your source must be your ajax request

```
source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/find_city",
        data: $('#search_text').val(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            // do something
        }
    });
}
```

and in your callback just return assign your desired value and label for the select input option element(s)

```
response($.map(data, function (item) {
    return {
        label: item.name,
        value: item.name
    }
}));
```

So you code would be like this

```
source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/find_city",
        data: $('#search_text').val(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.name,
                    value: item.name
                }
            }));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution to my issue. I have changed name field from cities table to value and it works like a charm. I could also use key field